# version v2 is little limited

Tags: box-api

There are limited v2 endpoints really. Its painful to switch gears when working with 2 versions of your API at the same time especially because each version returns different output formats. Imagine writing code when one api you call returns xml and another api you call returns json :)

Can you support json output for your original api which will make life little easier and I do not have to remember which ones send xml versus json?

Also, when are new endpoints planned to be released for sharing features?

Comment: I think if you frame this with a little more info, we can ask Robert if he will re-open the question.  This is clearly a question about the Box V2 API.  So I think if you re-state this as:

Comment: I think if you frame this with a little more info, we can ask Robert if he will re-open the question.  This is clearly a question about the Box V2 API.  So I think if you re-state this as:  "I am starting to look at the Box V2 API, and there are limited ..."   It may also help to provide a link to the Box Developers documentation, like a link to http://developers.box.com/docs/#files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v2 API is in beta and thus is going to be in flux for a little while. We're working through the initial release based on developer feedback and usage. We're going to release a /collaborations endpoint in addition to other sharing capabilities eventually, but we're going to optimize the current available endpoints first.

[Per the documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#api-basics), you can append '.xml' to API requests to have XML returned, which will let you work with v1 easier if you choose to develop against both simultaneously.

Comment: stackoverflow is not allowing people like me to ask questions here and removing or downvoting my questions. Is there any other box forum we can ask questions freely?

Comment: really?  Your question seems to be a legit tech question about the Box API.   I'm not sure why anyone would downvote it, but it is possible... that's part of the stackoverflow self-monitoring community.